# My floyd rose is badly sharp on return

Tags: electric-guitar

If I pull up on my whammy bar and then go to tune, the entire guitar is sharp. II have an Edge zero 2 on an Ibanez js140... any help?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the minor hazards with floating tremolos - they will go out of tune.

There are a few partial solutions:

- locking nut - this stops the string slipping through the nut and catching sharp or flat
- knife edge trem fulcrum - reduces the possibility of slipping out of tune
- zero point trem - springs both directions try to return the trem to an in tune position

They are all partial solutions though. In reality the best way to get back to perfect tuning is also learn the right behaviours. If you have pulled the string sharp, dip the trem slightly to flatten the rest position, and do the opposite if you have dive bombed.

That said, Ibanez trems should be pretty good, so you may want to check the locking nut is locked, there are no flat spots on the knife edges and the tension springs aren't catching on anything.